# How to build an iPhone app for distribution on the clients account?

Tags: iphone, build, distribution, ios-provisioning

I've developed a small app for my client which is supposed to be released under one of their brand names. They've created an iPhone developer account to be used for this purpose.

So far, for testing I provided them with ad hoc distributed builds using my own developer account. But how do I proceed about building their app store distribution build?

It is my understanding (from what I read in the "Program User Guide" on the provisioning portal) that only the team agent is able to create distribution certificates and build for distribution on behalf of his account. So, even if they add me as team member or team admin to their team, the team agent (one of my clients employees) would still need to do the final build.

However I don't want to provide them with the projects source, it's not part of the deal and none of their staff have the knowledge to actually build something in xcode - they're not even using macs.

So, how do I build an app for distribution via an account that is not mine, without surrendering my source?

Comment: Show them screenshots of the upload procedure, the needed information etc, package it in nice words and squeeze the password out of them...

Comment: I'd like that, would make my life (and theirs) easier. However I don't think they would let me do it for them, it's a rather large company and they're quite serious about security etc...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720193/can-i-submit-an-application-to-itunes-connect-that-is-signed-by-another-apple-dev/3171991#3171991).  Looks very similar - you don't have to provide source code, but they do need a Mac (or otherwise provide the distribution certs) to resign the binaries.

Comment: Speaking of providing distribution certs...: Would it be possible for their team agent to create and download a distribution certificate and send it to me, along with his private key? Would the key work on my machine, and would this impose any "security threats" to them?

Comment: They could send you their certs and private key, then after you had built and submitted (or handed off to them to submit) they can revoke those keys in their iPhone developer account.  Personally, I wouldn't be comfortable handing over my private keys to a 3rd party developer; but if they don't want to (or can't) do the distribution compilation or signing themselves I'm not sure what other options them might have.  You might send an email to Apple or hope somebody else chimes in with alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Just called ADC support and they basically told me that I would be able to build for distribution even in the team admin role... so either they changed something or I was unable to clarify my problem... We'll see. I'll accept your answer, because resignigning the app would solve the basic problems either way. I guess it's not my problem if my client has to buy a mac to accomplish this ;) 

Thanks again!

Comment: If you do get a resolution that works, post it as an answer here as well - I'd like to know how you eventually resolved it.  I'm sure you're not the only one in this situation. :)  Cheers!