# iPhone Developer account: Multiple Admins?

Tags: iphone

I am doing some dev work for a client. She has a Dev License should would like to put the app under but since she is non-technical it has been frustrating since she has to be the one to submit the final app.

Is there a way for a Dev License to have multiple Admins? I have it configured so I am a developer but as such I cannot do the Distribution License. Only she can do that. Is there a fix?

Comment: Only the license holder can submit the final app I believe. Just get her account?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a good relationship to your client, you might want to ask her for her login details so you can do it yourself.

There is one other possibility though: For a similar problem I was given the advice to build & archive my app and send the archive to the client. He could then resign the app using his certs, which would eliminate the need for him to do all the building stuff, not to mention it will spare you to surrender your source code. However, this will not eliminate the need for your client to enter all the meta information and so forth while uploading the app.

For the necessary steps to resign an app, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720193/can-i-submit-an-application-to-itunes-connect-that-is-signed-by-another-apple-dev/3171991#3171991).

To answer your original question: Each developer account has exactly one Team Agent. So you need some kind of workaround anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one administrative or Team leader per developer account.  So you really need to plan on the policy for sharing use of that account from the beginning, if the required activities of the agent need to be split up among multiple parties, if you can't have one party capable of doing everything.

A shared account can be created from the beginning (either by the owner or the developer).  I recommend an ADC account be created just for this purpose, instead of just using the owner's personal account and email address ( e.g. instead of mary.smith@sample.com, create and use iosdeveloper@sample.com for enrolling as an iOS developer. )

Account credentials can be "loaned" (perhaps with password changes after use).

You can be given remote access (VNC/RDP) into the owners PC or Mac (or more secure yet, a VM session) as or after they log in.

You can talk the owner though the process over the phone (or video chat, etc.).

Or, the owner can learn how to get certificates, and build or resign and submit apps themselves, perhaps using a comprehensive script.