# How can I sign a release iphone binary provided by a 3rd party?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have received an iPhone application developed for the company I work for by an outsourcing company. I do not have access to the source, only a compiled binary. I want to be able to sign it using our certificate, provisioning info, etc so I can submit it to the app store. How do I go about doing this? I'm aware of the existence of the `codesign` but can't really grok how to use it properly for iPhone from the man page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you have a distribution certificate created and installed, you can codesign from the Terminal like so:

```
cd <path to folder containing YourApp.app>

/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Your Company Name" --resource-rules=<full_path_to>/YourApp.app/ResourceRules.plist <full_path_to>/YourApp.app
```

This is what Xcode does when it signs an app.

Comment: Yes, not tested it myself but this is also the technique described by Erica Sadun here: http://www.tuaw.com/2009/06/24/dev-corner-signing-iphone-apps-for-informal-distribution/

Answer (score 1):

You've paid for an application to be developed, but you didn't get the source code in the deal?

I'd conservatively assume that the application is malware and abandon it. I'd certainly not sign it with my credentials without at least auditing the binary.

How do you expect to handle bug fixes/updates?

Comment: I haven't paid for anything to be developed, my employer has. I have absolutely no control over the business relationship with the other company and the first thing I asked for was the source. I have raised every grievance I could think of (including the ones you enumerated) with my employer, and they all fell on deaf ears. Ultimately, when you work for someone else, they have the power to say "just do it", no matter how wrong it may seem to you and I. Problem is, I can't quite work out how.

Comment: @Shabbyrobe So if Apple rejects the app, how do you plan to address their concerns? Do you at least have some maintenance relationship worked out?

Comment: No idea. Not my problem until my boss tells me it is, and I have already iterated these concerns to him. Once again, the problem here is how to accomplish the task I have been set in spite of my stated misgivings about its nature.

Comment: Shabbyrobe - Did you sign the binary using the command I posted above?  It should do exactly what you want.  Your post immediately above this one seems to indicate you haven't been successful yet.

Comment: Oh, sorry par, it worked fine. I was speaking more to why I needed to ask the question on here rather than any lack of success I had had with the answer you proffered.

Comment: Good to hear it and thanks for the points. I for one completely understand your situation, sometimes you've just got to do whatever idiotic thing management wants, despite your saner objections.

Comment: Glad to hear you found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a distribution certificate from your developer program and install it in your system. Now make an app store provision profile and use that to code sign the project.

You can make the app store binary same as how you make the adhoc binary. You don't need the entitlements.plist though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I may have miscommunicated the question. I actually already have a compiled app binary. I don't have the source code. I have been led to believe it is possible to sign that binary using the codesign tool, but I can't quite work out how.