# Can an app provisioned in one iOS developer account be submitted in a different iTunes Connect account?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, user-accounts, itunes-store

I noticed something strange in our iTunes connect and iOS developer accounts. We have a single provisioning profile. It is active, of type "distribution", connected to a not-yet-expired certificate, and has a single device listed under "devices". The app ID it specifies, however, is not listed in our iTunes Connect apps. Based on what I could gather from the app store, it seems that this app is held in a separate iTunes Connect account, which belongs to one of our contractors. Likewise, in our iTunes Connect account, we have an app listed that has no provisioning profile in our iOS dev account. Presumably, the provisioning profile for this app in our iTunes Connect account is in one of our contractors' iOS develeoper accounts. **Is this possible?**

[This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720193/can-i-submit-an-application-to-itunes-connect-that-is-signed-by-another-apple-de) would make it seem as if this isn't possible, but it's possible I'm missing a subtle difference between their situation and our own. If it isn't possible, where is the app in our iTunes Connect account provisioned?

Finally, can you create a provisioning profile using a certificate from a separate iOS developer account? In other words, is it possible that our dev account contains the certificate for the app in our iTunes connect account, in spite of it not being provisioned in our iOS dev account?

Thanks for your help. This is my first experience with apple's app store and it all seems very amorphous to me.

Comment: Can you just create new provisioning profile that matches the account you will be submitting under?

Comment: @JoshuaDance , yes, for submitting new apps. But I'm curious as to how our iTunes connect account has an app in it for which we have no provision profile. I also want to revoke unnecessary distribution certificates, but I want to confirm that its impossible that they're being used for provision profiles in other accounts.

Comment: See this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan indeed, and based on everything I've read and my experience so far, it seems that no, this isn't possible. my confusion was that we didn't have a provisioning profile for the app in our iTunes Connect account. I suppose someone must have deleted it before I got here; I can't think of any other explanation.

Comment: @mike did you manage to achieve this scenario? Was it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation what I understood is you want to upload the same app with a different developer account right? If this is what you want then you can upload the same app in two different Apple ID's but both the bundle identifiers should be different. If I understood wrong please let me know.

Comment: Not exactly- I just want to understand if it's possible to upload an app that's provisioned in one developer account, associated with one apple id, to an itunes connect account associated with a different one. I want to understand if it's possible the app in our iTunes connect account is provisioned elsewhere, and if so, if it's possible that it's still using one of our distribution certificates.