# Can I transfer an app to another account once its up under my account?

Tags: iphone

We have a company account for the iOS developer program.

One of our clients wants to put the app we developed for them up under their own company name, but they've only just sent off for enrollment and as such they want to put the app up under our name until they get their enrollment though.

Is it possible to "swap" the app to their account once theirs is set up?

Thanks

Comment: Per the faq, this is on-topic as a "matter unique to the programming profession."

Comment: the question is quite good  but it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store

Comment: Thanks william - I did check the FAQ and felt it was acceptable to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got this email from iTunesConnect!

> Apps can now be transferred from one developer to another within
>   iTunes Connect, for example after an acquisition or when a
>   distribution deal expires. Transferring the ownership of an app does
>   not affect the app’s availability on the App Store. All ratings and
>   reviews will be transferred and your customers will continue to have
>   access to all available app updates.
>
> To transfer an app, go to the app’s App Summary page in the Manage
>   Your Applications module on iTunes Connect and click Transfer App.
>   Make sure that:
>
> - Your account is active
> - You have accepted the most current version of    your contracts
> - Your app has at least one approved version
> - Your app is    in the Ready for Sale, Invalid Binary, Rejected, Developer Rejected,    or Developer Removed from Sale state
> - Any associated In-App Purchases    are in the Ready to Submit, Ready for Sale, Rejected, Developer    Removed from Sale, or Approved
>     state
> - You know the Apple ID of the    recipient’s Team Agent and their Team ID.
>
> For more information on app transfer, see the video tutorial on iTunes
>   Connect. To find answers to common questions about app transfer, see
>   the FAQ on iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has come up in the past.  I know it used to be that you had to get Apple to do this manually, and it took a long time to boot.  I imagine they'd like to improve their process for it, and I'd suggest contacting them to ask where they are at with it.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it. Apple is really slow answering support question so you can easily loose like few  months to transfer the app. But it is doable as stated here: [Transferring ownership of an iPhone app on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store/2706369#2706369)

Comment: ah thanks. :) did have a quick search, but I obviously didn't choose the best search terms. :p

Comment: @Thomas, Have you try to google with 'site:stackoverflow.com'? It gives much better results: "site:stackoverflow.com appstore transfer app"