# Transfer iOS app to another developer

Tags: ios, app-store

Suppose developer A posts an app to the App Store, and then wants to allow developer B to take ownership (and be responsible for future updates).  Is this possible, and if so, what is involved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask Apple to do it and it usually takes a while.

See this post: [Transferring ownership of an iPhone app on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store)