# Transfer ownership of an App including banking without affecting current rankings

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transferring ownership of an iPhone app on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store)

I created an app under a single developer license, submitted it to the app store and watching it flourish over the last year.  The app should really be registered to the company that I work for rather than my own personal account so we are looking at the best way to transfer ownership to my current employer without affecting ratings, rankings and current position in the market.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Asked previously?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store

Answer (score 1):

You should contact Apple developer support and ask them directly, you'll get a response faster and it will be 100% accurate.

Also see this question: [Transferring ownership of an iPhone app on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store)