# New version release to app store under completely different profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

So I took over an existing iOS app from a client, that is currently available for public use through the App Store. When I was given the project in xcode, I noticed that all provisioning profiles associated with the app had expired and all were under the name of the previous developer.

So, I added myself as a developer and joined the team and code signed the development copy under my credentials. I created a new ad hoc provisioning profile for testing, and released a version through TestFlight to some registered devices. No problems. The app is greenlighted to go live.

Can someone please help me out with the release process from this point on? Do I create a third new provisioning profile for App Store release, and tie it to the code signing in XCode? Is this going to be problematic considering the version that is live now is under completely different (expired) profiles from a different developer? Is there some alternative way I need to do it through Apple? I'm trying to be super cautious here... if for some reason I release the app and its crashing because of some step I didnt take by accident, the poop will hit the fan.

Comment: I answered this but then decided to turn it into a comment: I don't think you can change the developer certificate. Marco Arment (@marcoarment on Twitter) talked about this on his podcast. He went from Marco Arment to Instapaper LLC and had to do a re-release on his app, and give up all of his reviews and ratings.  Your other issue is no big deal. If you can get an app up and running, you don't need to worry about it crashing on end users' devices because of an "App Store certificate signing problem"

Comment: Wow.. I was afraid of that, and I certainly have no reason to doubt you. I'm a bit surprised... I mean, what I'm doing right now can't be that rare of an occurrence.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store

Comment: The thing about Marco and Instapaper up there, I'm not sure if that's exactly true. It may be more along the lines of his existing app not showing "Instapaper LLC" as the developer (on the App Store results) even after he changed the name of his company. I can't edit the old comment now

Comment: Is the client giving you the app because they are no longer interested in developing it? Or, are you just the new developer they hired, and they fully intend to keep it as their own? In the latter case... see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to release it under a new name on the App Store and forfeit all the ratings and reviews. Apple won't let you swap developer profiles on an existing app.

Other developers may disagree, but it looks like a huge PITA. See here

[Transferring ownership of an iPhone app on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store)

The official answer seems to be NO

Comment: Did a bit of research on my own before you answered, and I would agree. Looks like thats the word out of the horses mouth as well. You would think it would be easier. Oh well, I actually just got off the phone with my client and they are okay with the resubmission.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't interpret the question as regarding change of ownership of an app.

I read the question as: I've inherited maintenance of an app and we'll want to submit an update as the same seller.

In this case, you can generate your own certificates and distribution profiles, and you can then build and submit the app.

I have done this numerous times. That is, I have inherited responsibility for an app that I did not necessarily craft originally. I easily created new signing and provisioning credentials, appropriate for the app the be submitted as the seller (not me) on their behalf.

And for what it's worth, the App Store Distribution profile is necessary, but only used when the app is submitted, so Apple can ensure that it is coming from a developer that has the right to submit it. (Remember, these profiles are signed with the same certificates used to sign your app package.) If that Distribution profile should expire or change, it has no bearing on an app already in the App Store.

Comment: Yea he should clarify that. It says he's made himself part of the team, which would entail having access to the provisioning portal for that developer

Comment: Just wanted to reply for sake of clarity, sorry if I wasnt specific. The original developer and the owner of the app had a falling out. A pretty bad one. So the owner wanted all ties cut including anything with Apple that has their name on it. So yes, I inherited "maintenance" of it (which includes new development). It's a moot point in this case for me, because they are okay with the app being resubmitted as new, which I think we HAVE to do because they are changing the name of the app as well. I certainly appreciate all the help from the both of you.