# Change iOS developer id for an app

Tags: ios

is it possible to change between two different "seller"s using the same app? I mean, there is a company working on the first version of my app, but then I would code and release new updates for that app and I don't know if it's possible because our accounts are different.

Thanks,

Comment: simple answer to your question NO. You can release both different apps from two different accounts

Comment: This is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5575847/312312
It is also mentioned in the iTunes FAQ, under "Manage your Applications"

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible. The best way to prevent getting yourself in the same situation again is to open your own dev account.  Then when you appoint your contractors you can add them as members of your dev team and remove them once the project is finished.

This way you can simply hand over the source from one contractor to the next.