# How to change my app’s developer name on Apple's App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

When I paid Apple the $99 to open my developer account, my company was not yet legally registered, so I used my name. But now my startup is a registered company and I need to have the company’s name showing as the developer.

Does anyone know how to change the developer name? I already ready through [Transferring ownership of an iPhone app on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store) and that’s is not exactly what I am looking for:

I'm not trying transfer the account to a different company. I just want to setup somehow so that the company’s name is what is shown as the developer.

Answer (score 35):

1. Enter here: https://developer.apple.com/account/
2. Press "Membership" (on the left list, 2nd button)
3. Press "Need to edit this information?"

And choose what you need and fill the form
I did before
That's all :)

Answer (score 16):

Apple has answered this question under [Account Management](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.php) section. Solution still remains same as pointed by Undo.

**If I am enrolled as an individual, can I change to a company membership?**

Yes. To convert your iOS Developer Program membership from an individual to a company, please contact us. You can make this change only if you are the founder/co-founder of the company. As part of the conversion process, you may be asked to submit business documents to verify your company's identity.

Comment: The link appears broken :(

Comment: @RohitSingh use link [here](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/?entityType=individual&requestType=migrateAccount)